# VSTO C# Shape.TextFrame.HasText or shape.Type throws ComException (after upgrade)

Tags: c#, vsto

Some code that has been working without issues has just started to throw ComExceptions. To give you a bit of context..

```
Document wordTemplate = {a word document}
foreach (Shape shape in wordTemplate.Shapes)
{
    if (shape?.TextFrame != null && shape.TextFrame.HasText != 0)
    {
        foreach (Field fld in shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields)
        {
            if (fld.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldMergeField)
            {
                fld.Select();
                FindReplaceMergeField(wordApp, fld.Code.Text);
                fld.Update();
                
            }
        }
        shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields.Update();
    }
}

void FindReplaceMergeField(_Application wordApp, string fieldText)
{
    wordApp.Selection.Text = fieldText;   
}
```

In other words, a word document is opened, iterated through to find 'mergefields'. If there is a TextBox in the document, a comException is thrown when the shapes are being iterated.

Has anyone seen this?

Notes: Worked alright in office/word 2019 until a recent security update.

Thank you all for your time.

UPDATES..

Here is the exception...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked the code slightly to get the range instead... here is what worked for me.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= wordTemplate.Shapes.Count; i++)
{
    var shapeRange = wordTemplate.Shapes.Range(i);
    for (var j = 1; j <= shapeRange.Count; j++)
    {
        if(shapeRange[j].TextFrame.HasText != 0)
        {
            foreach (Field fld in shapeRange[j].TextFrame.TextRange.Fields)
            {
                if (fld.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldMergeField)
                {
                    fld.Select();
                    // do what needs to be done...
                    fld.Update();
                }
            }
            shapeRange[j].TextFrame.TextRange.Fields.Update();
        }
    }
}
```